# Specific case of c scanf()

Tags: c

Input : [1,3,2,4]

I want to make `arr[4] = {1, 3, 2, 4}` from this input using `scanf()`. How can I do this in **C language**?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre] of *your own* attempt, and [edit] your question to show it together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: You probably can't do that with just `scanf()`.

Comment: Are the brackets `[ ]` part of the input?

Comment: Yes they are part of it.

Comment: Are you asking for a solution specific to a **four-element** array?

Comment: And if the number of values in the "list" can vary (it's not always four) then using the format of the input you show, `scanf` is not really a good solution. The `scanf` function is useless for almost everything but the most trivial input.

Comment: No I want to make a code which can apply to any size of array.

Comment: Can there be whitespace around the commas and / or the square brackets?

Comment: A shape of input is fixed : [n1,n2,n3,...,nk]. There is no whitespace in input.

Comment: And is the number of elements known in advance, or does that have to be determined from the input?

Comment: The latter is right.

Comment: I want to find a method to ignore '[', ']', ',' and only accept integer units.

Comment: That sounds like an entirely different question.  Are we to assume, then, that for the purposes of the question, you are not interested in the issues surrounding allocating space to store an arbitrary number of elements?  And that you do not need to specifically recognize or distinguish among the `[`, `[`, and `,`?

Comment: If input is like "1 3 2 4", it is easy to make a code. I only have to use `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {scanf("%d", &arr[i])}`. However if input is like "[1,3,2,4]", I wonder how I can make an integer array.

Comment: I realize we've given you way more questions than answers, but the other important question is: how do you want to handle malformed input?  That is, what if one or both brackets are missing, or there are two commas with no number between them, or if there are characters other than brackets and digits and commas in the input?  If you're only interested in handling correct input (if the program can fail arbitrarily badly on bad input), this is pretty straightforward to solve.  If you'd like to handle bad input gracefully, it'll be much more elaborate (and probably impossible using just `scanf`).

Comment: It will be much easier for us to help you if you can show us your best shot at solving this: what you've tried, what input cases you've managed to handle so far, what cases you still need help to handle properly.  See also [this nice essay](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/21/find-a-simpler-problem/) on solving a hard problem in stages, by solving simpler problems first, and working your way up.

Comment: The size of an array is not 4 but it will be given as **n**

Comment: @SteveSummit
Inputs can be like : 

[1,2,3,4]

[42]

[1,1,2,3,5,8]

[]

Comment: I hope you don't want to solve this with one single `scanf` call.  You are going to need a loop.  Your first call could be something like `n = scanf("[%d %[],]", &x, &c)`.  If `n` comes out 0 you've read 0 numbers and you're done. If `n` comes out 2 and `c` is `']'` you've read 1 number and you're done.  If `n` comes out 2 and `c` is `','` you've got more numbers to read.  For the rest of the numbers you'll need a loop and a slightly-modified call: `n = scanf("%d %[],]", &x, &c)`.  (Beware: I have not tested this, and I don't like it: the notation `%[],]` is cryptic and wrong-looking.)

Comment: Please add more information to the post regarding limitations and requirements to the allowed input and how will or may be handled.

Comment: I think using `scanf("%s", string)` could be more effective. Thank you for your effort @SteveSummit and I think I can solve this problem by myself from now on.

Comment: @user13684416 Open ended requirements like "I want to make a code which can apply to any size of array." is something to avoid in software contracts.  Better to have an upper bound, like `65535`, `SIZE_MAX`, etc.

Comment: @user13684416  What is the range of potential integer values?  Same as `int` or something else?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to parse input such as you describe with `scanf`, but each `scanf` call will parse up to a maximum number of fields determined by the given format.  Thus, to parse an arbitrary number of fields requires an arbitrary number of `scanf` calls.

In comments, you wrote that

> I want to find a method to ignore '[', ']', ',' and only accept integer units.

Taking that as the focus of the question, and therefore ignoring the issues of how you allocate space for the integers to be read when you do not know in advance how many there will be, and assuming that you may not use input functions other than `scanf`, it seems like you are looking for something along these lines:

```
int value;
char delim[2] = { 0 };

// Scan and confirm the opening '['
value = 0;
if (scanf("[%n", &value) == EOF) {
    // handle end of file or I/O error ...
} else if (value == 0) {
    // handle input not starting with a '[' ...
    // Note: value == zero because we set it so, and the %n directive went unprocessed
} else {
    // if value != 0 then it's because a '[' was scanned and the %n was processed
    assert(value == 1);
}

// scan the list items
do {
    // One integer plus trailing delimiter, either ',' or ']'
    switch(scanf("%d%1[],]", &value, delim)) {
        case EOF:
            // handle end of file or I/O error (before an integer is read) ...
            break;
        case 0:
            // handle input not starting with an integer ...
            // The input may be malformed, but this point will also be reached for an empty list
            break;
        case 1:
            // handle malformed input starting with an integer (which has been scanned) ...
            break;
        case 2:
            // handle valid (to this point) input.  The scanned value needs to be stored somewhere ...
            break;
        default:
            // cannot happen
            assert(0);
    }
    // *delim contains the trailing delimiter that was scanned
} while (*delim == ',');

// assuming normal termination of the loop:
assert(*delim == ']');
```

Points to note:

- it is essential to pay attention to the return value of `scanf`.  Failure to do so and to respond appropriately will cause all manner of problems when unexpected input is presented.
- the above will accept slightly more general input than you describe, with whitespace (including line terminators) permitted before each integer.
- The directive `%1[],]` attempts to scan a 1-character string whose element is either `]` or `,`.  This is a bit arcane.  Also, because the input is scanned as a string, you must be sure to provide space for a string terminator to be written, too.
- it would be easier to write a character-by-character parser for your specific format that does not rely on `scanf`.  You could also use `scanf` to read one character at a time to feed such a parser, but that seems to violate the spirit of the exercise.

Comment: UV for `using scanf()` as spec'd by OP and the advice: " easier to write ... does not rely on scanf".

Comment: I love the fact that `%1[[,]` works, while `%1[,]]` *seems to work* until you get to the end of the input syntax... 

Comment: @chux, I have updated the code as you suggest.  However, I am supposing that the handling for cases other than 2 would involve terminating the loop without testing the contents of `delim`.

Answer (score 0):

While I think that John Bollinger answer is pretty good and complete (even without considering the wonderful `%1[[,]`), I would go for a more compact and tolerant version like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t arr_input(int *arr, size_t max_size)
{
    size_t n;
    for (n = 0; n < max_size; ++n) {
        char c;
        int res = scanf("%c%d", &c, arr + n);
        if (res != 2
            || (n == 0 && c != '[')
            || (n > 0  && c != ',')
            || (n > 0  && c == ']')) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *test_strings[] = { "[1,2,3,4]", "[42]", "[1,1,2,3,5,8]", "[]", 
        "[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]", "[1,2,3]4" };
    size_t test_strings_n = sizeof test_strings / sizeof *test_strings;

    char filename[L_tmpnam];
    tmpnam(filename);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < test_strings_n; ++i) {
        freopen(filename, "w+", stdin);
        fputs(test_strings[i], stdin);
        rewind(stdin);
        int arr[9];
        size_t num_elem = arr_input(arr, 9);
        printf("%zu: %s -> ", i, test_strings[i]);
        for (size_t j = 0; j < num_elem; ++j) {
            printf("%d ", arr[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        fclose(stdin);
    }
    remove(filename);
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is that you allocate space for the maximum number of integers you accept, then ask the `arr_input()` function to fill it up to `max_size` elements.

The check after `scanf()` tries to cope with incorrect input, but is not very complete. If you trust your input to be correct (don't) you can even make it shorter, by dropping the three `||` cases.

The most complex thing was to write the test driver with tmp files, strings, reopening and such. Here I'd have loved to have `std::istream` to just drop a `std::stringstream`. The fact that the `FILE` interface doesn't support strings really bugs me.

Answer (score -1):

```
int arr[4];
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)    scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
```

Are you asking for this? I was little bit confused with your question, if this doesn't solve your query, then don't hesitate to ask again...

Comment: That will not work.  It will not get past the leading `[`, or if you pre-read that, then it will not get past the first `,`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The size of an array is changeable and '[', ']', ',' in a input should be ignored and only integers in input should be included to integer array.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

use scanf to read a string input from user then parse that input into an integer array
To parse you can use string function "find" to locate the "," and "[]" and then use "atoi" to convert string into integer to fill the destination input array.

Edit: find is a C++ function.
the C function is [strchr](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strchr.htm)

Comment: What is `find`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky sorry I mixed C & C++, find is the C++ string function that searches the string for a specific character, I will edit my answer to reflect the correct functions for C